# Raiz com BigDecimal

Tags: java, matemática, conversão-de-tipo, decimal

Estou quebrando cabeça pra transformar uma raiz em código.
[image: Segue a foto da raiz com índice]

Sei que funciona mais ou menos assim:

```
Math.pow(625, (1.0/4)) = raiz 4ª de 625 = 5
```

Minha dor de cabeça é que meus dados são `BigDecimal`s

```
Sting prazoIn = idtText.getText();
BigDecimal prazo = new BigDecimal(prazoIn);

String valorIn = idtText.getText2();
BigDecimal valor = new BigDecimal(valorIn);


BigDecimal umPonto = new BigDecimal(1.0);

//Não sei como fazer com valores BigDecimais
BigDecimal raiz = Math.pow(valor, (umPonto.divide(prazo);
```

Comment: Evite usar `Math.pow` para trabalhar com `BigDecimal`. Você perde as propriedades desejadas

Comment: Como eu faria o calculo em questão com valores BigDecimais?

Comment: uma treta matemática envolvendo logaritmos e exponenciais, estou me lembrando aqui o como

Comment: Ou usar uma biblioteca externa: https://github.com/eobermuhlner/big-math

Comment: Estou tentando me lembrar a API do `BigDecimal` para ver as operações disponíveis

Comment: Bem, eu usava uma biblioteca para fazer os cálculos de logaritmos e exponenciais, então vou ficar devendo =\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Infelizmente não tem uma solução pronta. Se converter para outro tipo for uma opção válida, então não tem porque usar o `BigDecimal`. A conversão provocará perda de valor, e pior, de forma que muitas vezes testes ingênuos não detectarão.

Como o Java não provê nada pronto tem que fazer uma função própria. [Tem uma no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42649621/221800):

```
public static BigDecimal powerBig(BigDecimal base, BigDecimal exponent) {
    BigDecimal ans = new BigDecimal(1.0);
    BigDecimal k = new BigDecimal(1.0);
    BigDecimal t = new BigDecimal(-1.0);
    BigDecimal no = new BigDecimal(0.0);
    if (exponent != no) {
        BigDecimal absExponent =  exponent.signum() > 0 ? exponent : t.multiply(exponent);
        while (absExponent.signum() > 0){
            ans =ans.multiply(base);
            absExponent = absExponent.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE);
        }
        if (exponent.signum() < 0) {
            // For negative exponent, must invert
            ans = k.divide(ans);
        }
    } else {
        // exponent is 0
        ans = k;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/PowerBig.java).

Também tem [opção da raiz quadrada](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13649703/221800).

Tem bibliotecas prontas:

- [Cornell University](https://arxiv.org/src/0908.3030v2/anc/org/nevec/rjm/BigDecimalMath.java)
- [Suanshu](http://numericalmethod.com/suanshu/)

Comment: Creio que no lugar da comparação das referências de `exponent` e `no` se deveria usar uma comparação do conteúdo com `equals`; sair de `if (exponent != no)` para `if (!exponente.equals(no))`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado é possível, eu apenas peguei o que tem no SO, não verifiquei se é correto.

Answer (score 0):

Faz dessa forma, dependendo do tamanho da precisão que você estiver precisando, resolve..

```
public BigDecimal raiz() {
    return new BigDecimal(Math.pow(new BigDecimal(1.172544).floatValue(), (1.0 / 7)));
}

//retorno 1.022999903326536230707688446273095905780792236328125
```

Comment: Realmente insistir no `Math.pow` passando tudo para ponto flutuante é opção válida, apesar de que creio que a perda da precisão possa vir a fugir do intuito purista de se fazer operações com `BigDecimal`. E se for feito com `doubleValue` você mantém uma maior precisão de cálculo

Comment: Obrigado pela dica